# HTML5 Updating Offline cache

Tags: html, cache-manifest

How to update the offline cache?
I have five files on server html, css, js, images(folder) and a manifest file.
I have made some changes in the css file and replaced it with the older css, but it is not effecting when the page is loading. Its displaying the old data which was cached at the first time, as i am embedding the url in an iPad app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm not mistaking you just have to modify the manifest-file, cfr. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#appcacheevents.